# How can I map a HTML template to the LEFT, NORMAL and RIGHT areas in the page module of TYPO3?

Tags: php, typo3

I already have a page template made with HTML and CSS, and in it I have a few  elements that I would like to map to the Left, Normal and Right areas that you can see in the Page module, so I can easily add contents to them.

How can I accomplish this? I am using just markers, not TemplaVoila, and I have to deal without TemplaVoila for the moment.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's really no option to use TemplaVoila (which would be much easier!), take a look at 'Modern Template Building' http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/tutorials/doc_tut_templselect/0.1.0/view/

The content object lets you define the colPos (0 = main, take alook at tt_content which numbers the other ones have)

```
page.10 = CONTENT
page.10.table = tt_content
page.10.select {
      orderBy = sorting
      # Main column
      where = colPos = 0
}
```

(This is just off the top of my head, haven't used the 'classic' way for ages...)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use TV, you can try something like:

```
 page.10 {
 workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT

 marks.YOURMARKER_1 < styles.content.get
 marks.YOURMARKER_RIGHT < styles.content.getRight
```

}

Where `###YOURMARKER_1` and `###YOURMARKER_RIGHT###`should be the corresponding markers in your HTML file. Note that only markers in between ###DOCUMENT###  and ###DOCUMENT### will be eligible in this example.